# How to fix a scrapy spider that yields nothing

Tags: python, scrapy

the following spider creates a blank .xml file when run instead of one containing the items needed, can you spot the mistake(s)?

Please note, I'm an absolute amateur so using Occam's razor may be the easiest solution.

Spider code in arakaali.py:

```
import scrapy
from PoExtractor.items import PoextractorItem


class RedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "arakaali"
    start_urls = [
        "https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Araku_Tiki"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
            item = PoextractorItem()
            item["item_name"] = selector.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[1]/text()[1]").extract()
            item["flavor_text"] = selector.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[2]/span[3])").extract()
            yield item
```

Code of items.py:

```
import scrapy


    class PoextractorItem(scrapy.Item):

        flavor_text = scrapy.Field()
        item_name = scrapy.Field()
        pass
```

Then I use the command `scrapy crawl arakaali` but the result is a blank document.

The page I'm trying to extract data from is `https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Araku_Tiki`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow instead of `response` you use `selector` variable which is not defined, but you should get an error when run that code.

**UPDATE**:

You have an error in second xpath `"//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[2]/span[3])"` and should remove the last bracket in the expression (after `span[3]`)

Comment: Hello mizhgun, thanks for the reply, can you elaborate on what would it be your suggestion to make it produce results? - side note: it doesn't produce any error even though it doesn't work in the end

Comment: I substituted  
 `item["item_name"] = selector.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[1]/text()[1]").extract()`  
**With**  
 `item["item_name"] = response.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[1]/text()[1]").extract()`

Same result for now

Comment: Run it in debug mode `scrapy crawl spider_name -L DEBUG` and share the output

Comment: Ok now I see errors, seems the xpath is not valid, I extracted it using chrome inspect element. Opening the page, what I am looking for is the flavor text on the right: "It is said to make you invisible when the Great
Spirit comes to take you on your final journey." and the name of the item "Araku Tiki", here is the debug output [link](https://pastebin.com/pASFVVMH)

Comment: I updated the answer. Be careful copying the expressions.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue! Marked as solution